# How to implement test data in JSON file in data-driven unit test in .NET using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, unit-testing, xunit

I was doing unit test using xUnit package for my class library. I would like to try on JSON approach rather than normal object approach for data-driven unit test. However I don't see anywhere that able to achieve this.

What I am stucking at is data-driven test MemberData require the test data to be present in `IEnumerable<object[]>` type, when I call data from JSON file, it is in my data model class typed. Do I add them into the `IEnumerable<object[]>`? Or there is another way to do it?

Here's the code I have so far:

This is the json file which holds 5 test data:

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 12,
      "gender": "Male",
      "Hobby": "Reading"
    },
    {
      "name": "Susan",
      "age": 34,
      "gender": "Female",
      "Hobby": "Gardening"
    },
    {
      "name": "Larry",
      "age": 24,
      "gender": "Male",
      "Hobby": "Gaming"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": 3,
      "gender": "Male",
      "Hobby": "Sleeping"
    },
    {
      "name": "Minnie",
      "age": 15,
      "gender": "Female",
      "Hobby": "Partying"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is Test class file:

```
private User GetTestData()
{
     var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestData.json"); 
     var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
     var jsonStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
     var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

     var testDataObj = jsonObj["user"].ToString();
     var testData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(testDataObj);

     return testData;
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> ValidUserTestData()
{
     //What should I do here?   
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(ValidUserTestData))]
public void Test1()
{

}
```

Is this the correct way to implement this type of test? Or is there any other better options to use JSON file inside data-drive test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MemberData` attribute accepts an `IEnumerable<object[]>` of objects, which will be passed to your test method one by one. So, you should deserialize your JSON into array of objects (your json sample contains an array of `User` objects), and then return it from `ValidUserTestData` method. Also make sure, that `Test1()` accepts a correct parameter

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(ValidUserTestData))]
public void Test1(User user)
{
    //test logic against every User instance
}
```

`ValidUserTestData` can be declared per following: read the json first, than convert it to the enumeration of `User` objects and return it as an `IEnumerable<object[]>`

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> ValidUserTestData()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestData.json");
    var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
    var users = jobject["user"]?.ToObject<IEnumerable<User>>();

    foreach (var user in users ?? Enumerable.Empty<User>())
    {
        yield return new[] { user };
    }
}
```

Every single item in `IEnumerable<object[]>` represents an set of parameters, accepted by the test method. You'll need only one input parameter in your test method, so every `object[]` contains single `user` instance.

There is very nice article about it [Creating parameterized tests in xUnit](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/)

Comment: Note 1: Had to use the "Copy to Output Directory" file property settings  set to "Copy Always" for this to work.

Comment: Note 2: if you're able to use System.Text.Json, you can simply do return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<User>>(json); ... i.e. no need for the JObject, the ToObject method call, nor the foreach. Yes, you'll get a JsonReaderException if the file is empty, but this is a static xUnit file, it probably doesn't make sense for it to be empty anyway.